# Derivative, in order to find limit

Tags: calculus

I want to find the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt{n} \ln n}}{2^n}$$

When we apply the De L' Hospital rule, the derivative of the numerator is:

$$e^{\sqrt{n} \ln n} \left ( \frac{\ln n}{2 \sqrt{n}}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\right )$$

Is the derivative of the denominator equal to $$2^n \log 2$$ or $$2^n \ln 2$$?

Comment: aren't they the same?

Comment: @user160823 Nope $\log$ is the logarithm with base $10$ where as $\ln$ is the logarithm w.r.t base $e$

Comment: so it is $2^n ln 2 $

Comment: I mean $\log$ with base $2$,not $10$..

Comment: Do we have to use the same base at both logarithms?

Comment: [$$\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \ln a$$](http://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/calculus/derivative_proofs/a_to_the_x)

Comment: Nice!!!How an I apply De L'Hospital to find this:
$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n} $$

?

Comment: @evinda: Are you finding $\frac{d}{dn} n^{\sqrt{n}}$ difficult to compute. Just use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about it at first is:
$$
e^{\sqrt{n} \ln n} = (e^{\ln n})^\sqrt{n} = n^{\sqrt{n}}
$$
As per the question it's in your best interest to choose ln2,which is correct.
Intuitively a reason is because the derivatives have e^x as the neutral function i.e. (e^x)'=e^x so it's ln not log when it comes to derivatives.

Comment: A ok.. But how can I find the limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n} $$

?